# Selecting a string between something known and space before it

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a table column I have data like this (mssql 2005):

```
... something... 7000mAh ... something

... something... 610mAh ... something
```

The point is that I have 2,3 4 or even 5 digits before mAH.
I want to select all the digits up to the space before it, including mAh, like 610mAh, 7000mAh and so on.

Can somebody point me into the right direction?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Can you give some exact examples of data and expected output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Notice that a database should store "data", not "information". Usually sentences or strings that have multiple data things in it, should be in a different column. For example "the apple is red" should have two columns. Color with "red" and fruit_name with "apple". Maybe you should make a column "mAh" and put the digits in it, and select them from the database, and put the other "somethings..."  in a different column. Hope that makes sense

Comment: It's a large database, column holds products description and mAh characteristics must be replaced with new values and I need to select them somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you know that you'll only ever have those exact patterns then this will work. As @Derp said in the comments though, you're best bet is to get that data out from being embedded in a string - perhaps using the code below - more permanently.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (my_string VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @test (my_string)
VALUES
    ('test 12345mAh test;'),
    ('test 1234mAh test;'),
    ('test 123mAh test;')


SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]mAh%', my_string) > 0
          THEN SUBSTRING(my_string, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]mAh%', my_string), 8)
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]mAh%', my_string) > 0
          THEN SUBSTRING(my_string, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]mAh%', my_string), 7)
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]mAh%', my_string) > 0
          THEN SUBSTRING(my_string, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]mAh%', my_string), 6)
        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]mAh%', my_string) > 0
          THEN SUBSTRING(my_string, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]mAh%', my_string), 5)
        ELSE NULL
    END
FROM
    @test
```

Comment: This is working, it is selecting my targeted string correctly. Thank you!